# Request for HTTP gets logged as HTTPS and won't redirect

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, url-rewriting, iis-8.5

Man I have been struggling with this for a long time.  I really hope someone can help me figure this out.

- Windows Server 2012 R2
- IIS 8.5

Using URL Re-Write:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
                </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
     </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Pretty standard stuff.  Here's where it get's weird:

The rule above is in place on the parent site.  The redirect works MOST of the time on the parent site, but with some pages (and it's consistent) it will JUST. WILL. NOT. redirect them to HTTPS.

That parent site also has several sub-sites (web services, api's, others, etc). And on the sub-sites, NONE of the pages will redirect, even though it would appear as though the rule that was put in place on the parent site got inherited by all of the sub-sites.

Ok, and this is where it gets even more weird:

Using [this excellent tutorial](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/iis-7-troubleshooting), I set up Failed Request Tracing.  I then promptly tried to load one of the pages that is not redirecting by loading the page in a browser NOT on the web server. Example:

```
HTTP://v10staging.mydomain.com/some-sub-page
```

NOTE: I requested HTTP and not HTTPS. Then, I took a look at the Failed Logs, and this is what shows up:

[image]

Although I requested HTTP, it actually got logged as HTTPS.Tell me if I'm wrong, but it looks like the server thinks the request is already at https, and that's why it's not being redirected.

What. Is. Going. On?  And how do I fix it?

Comment: I just cleaned up the OP a lot to make it more readable and fix some typos